# What questions were migrated here from Arduino.SE?

Tags: support, arduino

The Arduino Stack Exchange site just closed. What questions were migrated here before it shut down?

Comment: Why these questions don't have [migrated] in the title?

Comment: Questions migrated *in* don't get the title change. Also, there's no migration history for these because the source is now inaccessible.

Comment: I've always thought we should use [emigrated] and [immigrated] to ease that confusion.

Answer (score 7):

The following 81 questions were migrated from Arduino.SE to EE.SE:

- [How can I use my SMD Arduino to program a separate DIP ATmega328?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67062/how-can-i-use-my-smd-arduino-to-program-a-separate-dip-atmega328)
- [How do I extend the number of analog (input) pins available to me?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67004/how-do-i-extend-the-number-of-analog-input-pins-available-to-me)
- [How can I create a serial bridge using two Bluetooth dongles?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67069/how-can-i-create-a-serial-bridge-using-two-bluetooth-dongles)
- [Is an Arduino capable of running 24/7?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67056/is-an-arduino-capable-of-running-24-7)
- [Building a menu and scheduler for a thermostat (rotary encoder for input, LCD screen)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67051/building-a-menu-and-scheduler-for-a-thermostat-rotary-encoder-for-input-lcd-sc)
- [Check the quality of not original Arduino boards?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67082/check-the-quality-of-not-original-arduino-boards)
- [Can I develop with the Arduino using an IDE with more features?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67160/can-i-develop-with-the-arduino-using-an-ide-with-more-features)
- [How to water-protect my Arduino?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67077/how-to-water-protect-my-arduino)
- [How can I safely connect both Arduino and a 120V 10A circuit?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67125/how-can-i-safely-connect-both-arduino-and-a-120v-10a-circuit)
- [What are the advantages of having USB part of the microcontroller (as the Leonardo does)?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/66990/what-are-the-advantages-of-having-usb-part-of-the-microcontroller-as-the-leonar)
- [Does the Arduino have any specific cooling requirements?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67174/does-the-arduino-have-any-specific-cooling-requirements)
- [Is there anything I should watch out for with cheap "Arduino" copies?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67033/is-there-anything-i-should-watch-out-for-with-cheap-arduino-copies)
- [Is there any difference between pin 13 and the rest of the pins?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/66987/is-there-any-difference-between-pin-13-and-the-rest-of-the-pins)
- [How much current can I draw from the Arduino's pins?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67092/how-much-current-can-i-draw-from-the-arduinos-pins)
- [Can I output a HDMI signal with an Arduino?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67098/can-i-output-a-hdmi-signal-with-an-arduino)
- [Does Arduino use step down voltage regulators?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67022/does-arduino-use-step-down-voltage-regulators)
- [Can Arduino be used in commercial products?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67030/can-arduino-be-used-in-commercial-products)
- [How can I distinguish between a clone and a real Arduino?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67042/how-can-i-distinguish-between-a-clone-and-a-real-arduino)
- [Maximum Current Draw on Vin Pin](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67201/maximum-current-draw-on-vin-pin)
- [Is it possible to program an Arduino in other languages?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67176/is-it-possible-to-program-an-arduino-in-other-languages)
- [Can I use a serial module with a barebones Arduino?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67085/can-i-use-a-serial-module-with-a-barebones-arduino)
- [Can I write a bootloader to Atmega using serial port](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/66977/can-i-write-a-bootloader-to-atmega-using-serial-port)
- [How can I use 5V devices and sensors with a Fio?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67188/how-can-i-use-5v-devices-and-sensors-with-a-fio)
- [How do I upload a hex file firmware to a target board without using the arduino IDE?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67121/how-do-i-upload-a-hex-file-firmware-to-a-target-board-without-using-the-arduino)
- [Would Arduino be an appropriate platform to teach high school students?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67131/would-arduino-be-an-appropriate-platform-to-teach-high-school-students)
- [How to discover memory overflow errors in the Arduino C code?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/66983/how-to-discover-memory-overflow-errors-in-the-arduino-c-code)
- [Does the Arduino Uno “Clean” the power input from the adapter?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67048/does-the-arduino-uno-clean-the-power-input-from-the-adapter)
- [How do I create a permanent application from something prototyped with Arduino?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67112/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-application-from-something-prototyped-with-arduino)
- [Is there any way that the Arduino board can get damaged by using a buzzer without a resistor?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67025/is-there-any-way-that-the-arduino-board-can-get-damaged-by-using-a-buzzer-withou)
- [What are methods to mitigate or reduce brown out resets?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/66972/what-are-methods-to-mitigate-or-reduce-brown-out-resets)
- [Can Arduino operate under water?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67096/can-arduino-operate-under-water)
- [Can I use the analog pins on the Arduino for my project as digital?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67103/can-i-use-the-analog-pins-on-the-arduino-for-my-project-as-digital)
- [How to connect RFduino to internet?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67198/how-to-connect-rfduino-to-internet)
- [Which board is the best fit for my project?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67153/which-board-is-the-best-fit-for-my-project)
- [Is there any way to simulate a program run before burning it onto the board?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67010/is-there-any-way-to-simulate-a-program-run-before-burning-it-onto-the-board)
- [What are the implications of using PROGMEM?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67038/what-are-the-implications-of-using-progmem)
- [Pin 13: Do I need a Resistor?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/66992/pin-13-do-i-need-a-resistor)
- [How do I use the flash memory on the Copperhead WiFi Shield?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67017/how-do-i-use-the-flash-memory-on-the-copperhead-wifi-shield)
- [How should one switch from using an Arduino as a programmer to an external programmer?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67080/how-should-one-switch-from-using-an-arduino-as-a-programmer-to-an-external-progr)
- [Working with a sensor and a motor, can I use both or should I use a motor shield?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67019/working-with-a-sensor-and-a-motor-can-i-use-both-or-should-i-use-a-motor-shield)
- [How do I transition from using the Arduino IDE to plain avrdude/make?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67067/how-do-i-transition-from-using-the-arduino-ide-to-plain-avrdude-make)
- [How should I power my permanentified project?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/66975/how-should-i-power-my-permanentified-project)
- [Unlabeled Headers/Pins on Arduino Uno](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67108/unlabeled-headers-pins-on-arduino-uno)
- [I burnt a pin. Now, what do I do?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67000/i-burnt-a-pin-now-what-do-i-do)
- [Can I connect two different 1-Wire Devices to the same data pin on an Arduino?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67065/can-i-connect-two-different-1-wire-devices-to-the-same-data-pin-on-an-arduino)
- [Problem stacking accelerometer and SD card shields on Arduino UNO](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67179/problem-stacking-accelerometer-and-sd-card-shields-on-arduino-uno)
- [Capacitors on Arduino Due](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67119/capacitors-on-arduino-due)
- [How to make an Arduino play a sound](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67075/how-to-make-an-arduino-play-a-sound)
- [Interfacing a 16x2 Character LCD to the Arduino](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/66997/interfacing-a-16x2-character-lcd-to-the-arduino)
- [How do I use a USB OTG cable to read a USB thumbdrive on Arduino Uno?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67100/how-do-i-use-a-usb-otg-cable-to-read-a-usb-thumbdrive-on-arduino-uno)
- [Hologram project](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67073/hologram-project)
- [Why do some pins have `~` signs next to their numbers?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67116/why-do-some-pins-have-signs-next-to-their-numbers)
- [Is it possible to remap the PWM output to other pins?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/66980/is-it-possible-to-remap-the-pwm-output-to-other-pins)
- [How do I interface an XBee wireless module with the Uno?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67168/how-do-i-interface-an-xbee-wireless-module-with-the-uno)
- [Efficient way to get multiple analogue voltages out of an Arduino?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67147/efficient-way-to-get-multiple-analogue-voltages-out-of-an-arduino)
- [Can I use a USB keyboard with the PS2Keyboard library?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/66995/can-i-use-a-usb-keyboard-with-the-ps2keyboard-library)
- [What are the most common ways to fry an arduino?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67149/what-are-the-most-common-ways-to-fry-an-arduino)
- [Are there different Ethernet shields available?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67053/are-there-different-ethernet-shields-available)
- [What's the difference between INPUT and INPUT_PULLUP?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67007/whats-the-difference-between-input-and-input-pullup)
- [Ethernet.begin() only works with SD Card removed - why?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67045/ethernet-begin-only-works-with-sd-card-removed-why)
- [Which version is my Ethernet Shield?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67014/which-version-is-my-ethernet-shield)
- [Is it possible to use a non-Leonardo board to act as a keyboard or other device?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67129/is-it-possible-to-use-a-non-leonardo-board-to-act-as-a-keyboard-or-other-device)
- [How can I control things without using delay?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67089/how-can-i-control-things-without-using-delay)
- [How should I light up all the LEDs?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67183/how-should-i-light-up-all-the-leds)
- [How can I control more than 64 LEDs using a Uno?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67191/how-can-i-control-more-than-64-leds-using-a-uno)
- [Simulate a bouncing ball on a LED cube](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67138/simulate-a-bouncing-ball-on-a-led-cube)
- [How can I mount a shield on a breadboard?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67141/how-can-i-mount-a-shield-on-a-breadboard)
- [analogRead(0) or analogRead(A0)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67087/analogread0-or-analogreada0)
- [Input impedance of Arduino Uno analog pins?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67171/input-impedance-of-arduino-uno-analog-pins)
- [Ensure serial has been written before executing next line](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67210/ensure-serial-has-been-written-before-executing-next-line)
- [Can the Arduino Leonardo act as a keyboard, mouse, and serial port at the same time?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67196/can-the-arduino-leonardo-act-as-a-keyboard-mouse-and-serial-port-at-the-same-t)
- [How to avoid SD Card and W1500 SPI mixup on the Ethernet Shield?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67212/how-to-avoid-sd-card-and-w1500-spi-mixup-on-the-ethernet-shield)
- [What library version is bundled with which version of the Arduino IDE?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67205/what-library-version-is-bundled-with-which-version-of-the-arduino-ide)
- [What are these spots on the PCB that are by the mounting holes?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67158/what-are-these-spots-on-the-pcb-that-are-by-the-mounting-holes)
- [Reduce the size of the Arduino bootloader?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67207/reduce-the-size-of-the-arduino-firmware)
- [Tell if interrupts are enabled](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67215/tell-if-interrupts-are-enabled)
- [How do you update the Arduino IDE?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67144/how-do-you-update-the-arduino-ide)
- [Are there any disadvantages to look out for when using Optiboot?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67110/are-there-any-disadvantages-to-look-out-for-when-using-optiboot)
- [Are there any DIP alternatives to the FT232R?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67181/are-there-any-dip-alternatives-to-the-ft232r)
- https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67204/how-can-i-get-my-arduino-duemilanove-to-work-with-windows-7
- [Can I reprogram my Arduino via a wifi shield?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67137/can-i-reprogram-my-arduino-via-a-wifi-shield)

In addition, the following questions were migrated from Arduino.SE to other sites on the network:

- https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/what-should-i-take-into-account-when-trying-to-decide-between-an-arduino-uno-or
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224732/how-to-use-delays-in-arduino-code
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224740/what-is-the-benefit-of-arduino-ethernets-library-ipaddress
- https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1229/limits-of-pwm-timers-and-interrupts
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224746/how-to-use-c11-to-program-the-arduino
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/196151/what-guidelines-should-i-follow-while-designing-a-library
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224789/does-using-more-voids-take-up-more-space-and-take-more-system-resources
- https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/how-can-i-use-the-arduino-pid-library-to-drive-a-robot-in-a-straight-line
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224801/how-can-i-port-an-arduino-program-to-net-for-use-on-a-netduino
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224816/preventing-reset-on-serial-monitor-connect

Comment: Thanks Shog9! We appreciate it. Welcome to the site, google bait.

Comment: Many of these don't belong here and shouldn't have been migrated. You should have left these questions where they were. Just because the arduino people don't now have a home on SE doesn't mean their stuff should be dumped here.  Now we have a bunch of questions to close.